# Need to stop site moving and re-sizing when browser is changed

Tags: html, css, joomla2.5

I hope somebody can shine some light on this for me. I have a new site that I have made with a joomla template, but I am having issues as I am very new to coding and web design.

I know that there are many questions like this on here but I am a real beginner and all of the answers seem to be aimed at people with some knowledge of html and css, whereas mine is limited.

Here is my site - www.findadj-uk.co.uk

When the internet browser is made smaller or the site is viewed on a mobile for example, it will re-arrange all of the content. All I want is for the site to stay the same, all fixed in the same position no matter what device or internet browser it is displayed on.

If anybody needs anymore info, in order to help me please just let me know what you want. I am very grateful in advance for any replies.

Comment: Remove the `responsive` css.

Comment: Thanks @NickR - Sorry but I am really new. Where would I find this and how would I remove it? If that's even a question that can be answered?

Comment: Well it looks like the theme utilises the Bootstrap framework as a base, this has responsive and non-responsive CSS (responsive being the media-queries used to change the CSS at different screen sizes) http://getbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 0):

This is called responsive layout and usually a feature, programmers spend a lot of time to achieve. You should really think about removing this as it is important for mobile users to be able to read your content. If you remove it they will need to zoom in a lot and scroll horizontally to read all the information.

IF you want to remove it, look for code like @media, combined with checks for min-width and max-width. You would need to rewrite them so that they always take the style for the biggest size. without any idea of css this might be hard to acheive. Mabye think about using a different theme?

Answer (score 0):

You have referenced some responsive CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/templates/ict_mucho/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/templates/ict_mucho/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/templates/ict_mucho/css/responsive_v1.css" type="text/css">
```

Remove them from the code.

Also, you're referencing the same bootstrap CSS by twice:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/templates/ict_mucho/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/templates/ict_mucho/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
```

The second one is the minified version which is recommended for data transmission. Keep the second one and remove the first one.